# Vim uses system ruby and python

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I have installed Python and Ruby using Homebrew and RVM respectively and they work fine in terminal, but Vim (both system and MacVim from Homebrew) launches system ones for some reason. `:! which python` returns `/usr/bin/python` while `which python` in console returns `/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: You can check the PATH by :! echo $PATH and echo $PATH in vim and in console separately. Then find out why they are different.

Comment: @rwxrwxrwx thanks, the PATH in Vim starts with `/usr/bin` and I've found the reason why.

Comment: Here's the description of why this is happening http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853584/how-to-use-correct-ruby-in-vim-how-to-modify-path-in-vim